# pandas get index of previous date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe with date a column, I want to add a new column with previous date index in the dataframe. How to achieve this?
Sample df:

```
index Date
0 2015-10-03 
1 2015-11-03 
2 2015-11-30 
3 2015-11-30  
4 2015-12-03
```

Desired output:

```
index Date previous_day
0 2015-10-03 0
1 2015-11-03 0
2 2015-11-30 1
3 2015-11-30 1 
4 2015-12-03 3
```

1. Since at index 1 there is no previous day i want 1 in previous day.
2. Since date at index 2 is same as index 3 I expect 1 in previous_day for index 3.

Thanks,

Comment: date at index 2 is not same as index 3!

Comment: @harshil9968 date at index 2 (2015-11-30) is same as date at index 3 (2015-11-30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need replace `index` of `duplicated` values of `Date` column to `NaN` and then forwarding filling these values. Also is necessary rename first value of index to `1` and last subtract `1`:

*Notice: Solution works only if unique monotonic index (`0,1,2,...`)*

```
#see notice above 
df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)

df['prev'] = df.rename(index={0:1})
              .index.to_series()
              .where(~df['Date'].duplicated()).ffill()
              .astype(int)
              .sub(1).values
print (df)
            Date  prev
index                 
0     2015-10-03     0
1     2015-11-03     0
2     2015-11-30     1
3     2015-11-30     1
4     2015-12-03     3
```

Comment: Yes, works fine, I am making sure unique monotonic index by `df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)`

Comment: Super, it was very nice idea ;)